# Assert.AreEqual with different numeric types but always with value long.MaxValue

Tags: c#

I am wondering why the third Assert fails and not already the second:

```
long l = long.MaxValue;    // is  9223372036854775807
decimal m = long.MaxValue; // is  9223372036854775807
double d = long.MaxValue;  // is 9.2233720368547758E+18

Assert.AreEqual(l, m);
Assert.AreEqual(l, d);
Assert.AreEqual(m, d);
```

EDIT: Hovering over the failing third Assert in Visual Studio reveals, that the overload which takes two values of type object is called whereas the first calls the (decimal, decimal)-overload and the second the (double, double)-overload. Therefore the behavior makes absolutely sense.

Comment: Because the double value has a decimal place in it and the first two values don't.

Comment: @DrewKennedy The decimal in the comments is just how `double` displays that value in scientific notation.  It's not failing because it's doing some type of comparison of the string representations.  It has to do with which value is getting cast to the other's type for the comparison.

Comment: @juharr Ahh. So is this due to `decimal`'s precision?

Comment: @DrewKennedy It's because the first two are actually `Assert.AreEqual<decimal>(l, m)` and `Assert.AreEqual<double>(l, d);`, but the last one is `Assert.AreEqual<object>(m, d);`.  So obviously `long.MaxValue` cast to `double` and `decimal` will match.  But the `object` one is going to fail because at that point it's comparing types and not values.

Comment: The reason those particular overloads are chosen is because there's an implicit cast from `long` to both `decimal` and `double` (basically all longs can be represented as either).  But there are no implicit casts between `decimal` and `double` as there are value of both that cannot be precisely represented by the other, so it has to fall back to `object`.